# Can't submit TextField in Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

Can't seem to find a reason why the first approach works, and the second doesn't.

Works: [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GGwgwCpJT5/)
Doesn't: [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/KkDHJFQcwm/)

The difference between these two is that there's `<TextField>` in the second one instead of `<div>` and `<Field>`. But the examples I've seen makes the `<TextField>` work just fine, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the component to `<Field />`:

```
<Field component={TextField} name="password">
```

Comment: You mean to rewrite <TextField> as <Field component={TextField}>? It doesn't change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are now trying to use it like so:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    render={props => (
        <Form>
            <TextField
                id="name"
                name="name"
                label="Name"
                value={props.values.name}
                onChange={props.handleChange}
                fullWidth
            />
        </Form>
    )}
/>
```

... Which should work, are you getting any errors in the console?

If that doesn't work for some reason you can try doing it via Field render props.
This snippet is taken from the Formik docs.

```
 <Formik
   ...
      <Field
        name="lastName"
        render={({ field }) => (
          <input {...field} placeholder="password" />
        )}
      />
   ...
/>
```

You see you can use a `render` props to the `Field` component to render a custom component if you like.

> There are 3 ways to render things with `<Field>`.
>
> Aside from
>   string-only component, each render prop is passed the same props for
>   your convenience.
>
> Field's render props are an object containing:
>
> field: An object containing `onChange`, `onBlur`, `name`, and `value` of the
>   field form: Formik state and helpers Any other props passed to field

See more in Formik docs [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field).

Comment: Are you saying material-ui's TextField must be inside Field? I don't follow.

Comment: @NeNenne I've updated my answer to elaborate. Please explain why the code you pasted doesn't work, do you get any errors?

Comment: It made it clearer for me, thank you. I found the issue - it's the validationschema. If I comment it out, I can submit successfully. Otherwise I press the submit button and nothing happens. Do you know what may be wrong with my validation schema?

Comment: @NeNenne you could try moving the `ValidationSchema` declaration out of the `render` function? make it a `const` before you render the component.
Also try removing the `required` form the `TextField` components as that is already declared in your `ValidationSchema`

Comment: Well, not exactly, I made it a constant outisde of render, but it didn't help. However I found [this](https://itnext.io/how-i-tried-to-validate-react-forms-with-hooks-31634fc5385b) post and rewrote the code, I think this method fits my use case better.

Comment: @NeNenne okay, well done! Does the form validation work as expected now?